# How can change text view visibility when i click it even it was hidden?

Tags: android, layout, textview

What i have is two text view, and what i am trying to do is when i start to write in one of them the other will be invisible which worked fine , and here is the code :

```
@Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                                textView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                });
              textView2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {                      
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     

                    }
                });
```

But the thing is , i want to reverse it too .. so if (textview) is hidden and i click on it's area while it's hidden , to return visible and the other one is invisible , how can i do this? any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can showing/hiding your 1st textView by checking if the 2nd textview is focused:

```
textView2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});

textView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            textView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT:

```
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
textView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
textView2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

Comment: it gave me an error on isVisible() , it says :The method isVisible() is undefined for the type AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: it didn't give me the result i want :( it make it invisible only but it doesn't reverse it when i click on the other one

Comment: @sereen obviously set a similar listener to the other textview too. Updated.

Comment: @sereen I read your question again, and only now I understood it sorry .. You will need a click listener too, that reveals the `TextView`'s. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>  
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

second linear layout has it's area.but inner textView does not show.so you can set onClick for it.

```
LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.txt1);  
final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
l1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @override
    public void onClick(View view){
       textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setVisibility()` method for doing this

```
//To make textView not visible
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

//To make textView visible
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```